# Compiling a Linux application in Delphi 10.4 Enterprise

Tags: delphi, cross-compiling

I am trying to compile an existing large windows (console) server application for Linux, using the Delphi 10.4 Enterprise IDE.
The problem is that the moment I switch to the Linux platform, even the most 'basic' items no longer exist, and I just have no idea how and where to add them, either as Delphi units, or do I have to find libraries in the linked Linux Virtual Machine, and then Delphi will find them there?

Is there somewhere a manual or book on how this is supposed to work?
Primary requirements:  I need TThread (Does not exist) and I need a MS-Windows lookalike Message system for it, to communicate between the Threads and the Main thread, passing Pointers to records in memory.

Any help whatsoever is very welcome.

Comment: *Windows (console) server app* is Windows specific. That code will not compile and work for Linux, because it's a Windows app. None of the functionality that it uses is available under Linux. Also, your problem description is pretty vague - "even the most 'basic' items no longer exist* is useless unless you tell us what those *items* are specifically.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the few first error messages you get. If you build a Windows *service*, it will require a lot of work to port to Linux. If you build a *server*, it depends on what you are using. Obviously, you can't use any Windows API function. Most Delphi RTL will work. If you want help, you have to be more specific and - as I already said - publish the error messages you get.

Comment: I think I did explain excatly what I am trying to do and what I need. It is a SERVER, and yes, I can switch easely between a Windows Console program then change the platform to Linux, and have the same output run under Linux. But what I do NOT have, is when I switch the platform to Linux from my Database Server program, is a TThread or any type of messaging system. The TThread does not exist anymore when I switch to Linux.

Comment: So where (and how) can I get a TThread system for Linux, and should this be part of the Delphi code, or is the compiler trying to find it in the Linux Virtual Machine? As I already stated...

Comment: A *server* means no much. A server servicing what. You also talk about your *Database server program*. Is it the same as *server*. That is not clear. But for sure, the Delphi TThread class works the same under Windows and Linux. See my answer below and try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal reproducible example of a thread that works compiled for Windows or Linux with **no** source code change and using Delphi 10.4.2:

```
program LinuxThreadDemo;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, 
  System.Classes;        // Contains TThread for both Windows and Linux

type
  TMyThread = class(TThread)
      procedure Execute; override;
  end;

var
  MyThread : TMyThread;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  WriteLn('Hello from thread');
end;

begin
  try
    MyThread := TMyThread.Create(TRUE);
    try
      MyThread.Start;
      ReadLn;
    finally
      MyThread.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: You are right. I stuffed up a IFDEF statement between MSWINDOWS and LINUX.

Comment: Now I am still looking for a solution to a message queue system, which I use to transfer pointers to records, between Threads. So as it is a Server application, and will run on a Debian based VPS Server (no graphics interface), how can this be done? In the Windows Service version, I generate a window to deal with the messages. (WHandle := AllocateHWnd(HandleServiceMessage); ). Not sure if something like that can be done under a Linux Debian Server.

Comment: Windows messaging API doesn't exists in Linux. But there is the POSIX message queue. Look at [this documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mq_overview.7.html). You may also use a `pipe` as a way to communicate between thread. The API to open/close is again not the same but the functionality is the same. Look at [this documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html).

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is now that I do not understand how I can reach all this from my Pascal code. It is also unclear to me how the IDE links itself to the Linux VM, that is, somehow it loads Linux libaries directly from the Linux VM, but after that, how am I supposed to reach these Linux libraries from my pascal code? I do not see any way to use a 'uses' clause for the Linux libraries. I also cannot seem to find any proper documentation on how the 'Compile for Linux' system actually works in Delphi 10.4 (and I had to pay a fortune to get access to this feature :(  )

Comment: @BartKindt Those are other topics worth opening several new questions. StackOverflow rules do not allow chatting in comments to solve several question deriving from an initial one. *Please mark my current answer as accepted* and open new questions based on your comment. Rewarding those answering is the best way to encourage new answers.

Comment: @BartKindt I don't see your next question published. Did I miss it?